# Fixing Transaction Management in an old ibatis application

Tags: transactions, ibatis

We're on ibatis 2.0 and it looks like there are some problems with the transactions - they open on service layers and service layers talk to service layers which doesn't seem to work due to transactions being opened in transactions.

So I want to do something like AOP with Spring Tx management but we use these DAOManagers which don't appear to be wirable with the SqlMapClient and rewrite is way out of the question.
Is it possible to get to proper tx?

Is there another option?